# How do I override the default client validation logic for numeric types in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a situation in which a number must be in the format `R$ 3.000,00` which is not compatible with the default validation logic for numeric types in the client unobstrusive validation.

I need a way to implement my own JavaScript function and override the default one.

How do I do that?

Comment: There's a great article about this very thing on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618485

Comment: @BradChristie: Thanks. It's indeed a great article, but it doesn't delve into how to override the default client validation funcions..

Comment: They key is to not override; it's to create your own.

Comment: @BradChristie - his problem is related to the jquery-validation on the client-side that MVC uses, you don't create your own for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific locale files to download for your locality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880(v=vs.98).aspx

There is also a good article here

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx